# check user validation in Asp.net core with jwt authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, access-token

I implemented Microsoft Identity and JWT in my web api,
a client can login  and get a JWT token and store it in the application. 
since the expiration of the token the user can access the the server,
but if I remove a user from my database, the removed user still has its token and can access the web api,
how can I check the validation of the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to validate the current user on the JwtBearerEvent OnTokenValidated event which will be triggered after every successful authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var userService = ServiceProvider.GetService<IUserService>();
                    if(userService.IsUserRemoved(context.Principal.Identity.Name))
                        context.Fail("User is removed");

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

Note: In this example I use ServiceProvider, to get the an instance of IUserService, which is stored in the Startup.cs class as a parameter. Initialized as `ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();` in the ConfigureServices method. The IUserService is a wrapper class where you need to implement the IsUserRemoved method which will operate on your user provider implementation.

Comment: I did as you said. but my userService in always null.

Comment: @MSjjD ok, have you registered it in the ConfigureServices like this services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();

Comment: now it works. thank you .  context.Principal.Identity.Name returns null. I am using context.Principal.Claims.First().Value instead. I works. but I think Its not good.

Comment: @MSjjD great! Please accept/upvote answer this answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I cant vote yet. I will as soon as I am able.

Comment: @MSjjD ok np! But why did you select the other answer as accepted answer?

Comment: Sry that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to implement and register your own `SecurityTokenValidator`. To do so you need to create a class implemented `ISecurityTokenValidator` interface:

```
//using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

public class CustomValidator : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
   //interface implementation
   ...
}
```

and register it as an additional token validator via [`JwtBearerOptions.SecurityTokenValidators` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions.securitytokenvalidators?view=aspnetcore-2.0):

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer( options => {

        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new CustomValidator()) 
    });
```