# JWT: Deleting users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

As I said in my other question ([JWT: Changing a user's role after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633941/jwt-changing-a-users-role-after-authentication)), I'm playing with asp.net Core WEB API. Similar to the problem I have mentioned in the other question, I'm wondering how to handle the deletion of user accounts.

Say I want admin users to be able to create **and delete** accounts. After deletion of an account, the JWT would still be valid and the user could continue using the API. Since I cannot revoke a JWT, I wonder whether it is possible to hook myself into some point (for example JWT validation) to check whether the user for the JWT is actually still there and if he is not, return an Unauthorized response?

**EDIT**
The following code is used to add the claims to the JWT:

```
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, m_configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
    new Claim("Id", user.Id.ToString()),
    new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName),
    new Claim("LastName", user.LastName),
    new Claim("UserName", user.UserName),
    new Claim("role", user.IsAdmin ? "Admin" : "User"),
    new Claim("EMail", user.EMail)
};
```

Comment: Does your JWT not contain any kind of id for the user? What information are in your JWT?

Comment: @Progman It does. Based on that ID I could perform such a validation, but I'd have to check whether the user is valid in every call. I thought there might be some point before my API even gets called, where I could inject this. As the JWT itself also needs to be validated at some point, I thought I could hook myself into this validation somehow?

Comment: Should have googled in more detail before. Seems I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586126/check-user-validation-in-asp-net-core-with-jwt-authorization. Sorry to interrupt...